# How to install node with home brew when "Brew postinstall node not working."

Tags: homebrew

I cannot get node installed on my computer because it keeps failing the post-install.

> Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
> You can try again using:
> brew postinstall node

when I reinput brew postinstall node I get the same error message.
Does anyone know what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to install it using *nvm* (node version manager) instead of homebrew. This allow to control which version is being use, brew is getting better to provide versioning but it definitely not the right chose for node

You can find more information about it [here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md)

> nvm allows you to quickly install and use different versions of node
> via the command line.

To install it, use:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
```

Edit your `~/.zshrc` file to include:

```
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

Then you can install node using:

```
nvm install <version>
```

Comment: got it working thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked for you and welcome to SO. Please don't forget to mark this answer as the accepted one if it worked :).

Comment: wonderful! Thank you!